# rabl - multiple nodes with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rabl

I am wondering is it possible using RABL to render xml like this (dont ask why i need such chaotic structure :D):

```
<garbagebox>
  <user><id>1</id></user>
  <user><id>2</id></user>
  <article><name>some name here</name></article>
  <customer><rich>yes</rich></customer>
  <article><name>some name here #2</name></article>
</garbagebox>
```

For now looks like rabl forbilds multiple nodes with same name within single parent (with exception of collections - but in collection all nodes are named the same)

For example, if i do smth like this:

```
object :garbagebox
child(Country.first) {attributes :id, :currency}
child(Customer.last) {attributes :id, :name}
child(Country.first) {attributes :id, :currency}
```

I get only 2 childs instead of 3.

Can someone please provide any tips so i can render such xml? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of hardcore monkey-patching. Use it at your own risk.

Before change:

```
object @user
child(@user) { attribute :name }
child(@user) { attribute :city }
child(@user) { attribute :name }
```

Results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <user>
    <name>leo</name>
  </user>
</user>
```

Monkey patch:

```
module Rabl
  module Helpers
    alias_method :data_name_without_uniquify, :data_name
    def data_name(data_token)
      uniquify(data_name_without_uniquify(data_token))
    end

    private

    def uniquify(object)
      Uniquificator.new(object)
    end

    class Uniquificator
      def initialize(object)
        @object = object
      end

      def ==(other)
        false
      end

      def hash
        @object.hash
      end

      def eql?(other)
        false
      end

      def to_s
        @object.to_s
      end

      def method_missing(*args, &block)
        @object.__send__(*args, &block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And result after patching:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <user>
    <name>leo</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <city>LA</city>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>leo</name>
  </user>
</user>
```

Comment: Thanks, see what u did here ;). Will wait some time for solution thats not monkeypatch, if none comes - will accept this as answer.